# C# object runtime type casting

Tags: c#, casting

I have a variable (I'll call it prop) whose type is "object", I know that the underlying type will always be some sort of ICollection. I'd like to iterate this collection and tostring all the elements.

My prop variable has a method GetType() which returns the type.

```
foreach (var item in prop as ICollection<PCNWeb.Models.Port>)
{
    //do more cool stuff here
}
```

The problem being I don't know what the inner type of the ICollection is at compiletime, (listed above as PCNWeb.Models.Port).

Calling `prop.GetType().ToString()` (in this case) yields `` System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[PCNWeb.Models.Port] ``

I can tell the information is there that I need, just not sure how to make it work.

**I've tried a number of things (albeit maybe incorrectly):**

Try 1:

```
Type t = prop.GetType();
foreach (var item in Convert.ChangeType(prop, t))
{
    //do more cool stuff here
}
```

Which yields:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Try 2:

```
Type t = prop.GetType();
foreach (var item in prop as t)
{
      //do more cool stuff here
}
```

Which yields:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Try 3: (Per @DarkFalcon's suggestion)

```
Type t = prop.GetType();
foreach (var item in prop as ICollection)
{
      //do more cool stuff here
}
```

Which yields:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

Comment: The entire point of interfaces is that you don't need to know the underlying type. For iterating over it, what is wrong with `ICollection` or even `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I think the OP actually wants to know the generic type parameter, not the actual implementation of ICollection.

Comment: Perhaps, but that is not what he was looking at or changing in his example code...

Comment: That's because he was trying to get the entire type (class and generic type parameter) To quote him: "The problem being I don't know what the inner type of the ICollection is at compiletime, (listed above as PCNWeb.Models.Port)." which was the generic type parameter.

Comment: Perhaps the OP could chime in here and clarify - are you looking for the actual class that implements the ICollection interface, or are you trying to find out what type of object the ICollection contains?

Comment: Hey @Tim I just need to be able to iterate the collection. I don't necessarily need the inner type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in prop as System.Collections.IEnumerable)
{

}
```

that should work. I think you're getting tripped up by having a `using System.Collections.Generic;` in your code file (so it thinks you want `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` instead of `System.Collections.IEnumerable`)

If you go look at [the documentation for `foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see this at the top:

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection that implements the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`

So basically you just have to get your `prop` to be referenced as one of those two types. Since you don't know T, then you should go with the non-generic one.

Answer (score 2):

you have to do like that:

```
foreach (var item in prop as System.Collections.IEnumerable)
{
    var t1 = item as Type1;
    if(t1 != null)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    var t2 = item as DateTime?;
    if(t2.HasValue)
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: They that looks like a good idea but I get this error: ```Compiler Error Message: CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments```

Comment: Use System.Collections.Enumerable not System.Collections.Generics.Enumerable

Answer (score 1):

Compile time type of `prop.GetType()` would always be an object.. If you are sure about the type you are using you can use `dynamic` type instead

```
dynamic proplist=prop;
foreach (dynamic item in proplist)
{
    item.method1();
    item.method2();
    item.method3();
}
```

Comment: Hey @Anirudh I just tried that and got this: ```Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'```

Comment: Although this does work, losing intellisense on the variable really sucks.

Comment: @TechplexEngineer indeed but if you are sure about the type,you can use it